# Updates to SolrConfig.xml file are not being reflected

Tags: solr, lucene

I added in a new request handler in the SolrConfig.xml file, however anytime I try to use the new handler I get back a 404 with "unknown handler" error.

Are there any other files to modify when the SolrConfig.xml file is modified?

Thanks

Comment: nope. Did you reload the config ? restart the server ? Can you add you solrcoonfig.xml and the url you are trying ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restart the container (Tomcat or Jetty) where you have Solr running in order for the changes to the solrconfig.xml to accessible.

Comment: You can also issue a RELOAD command if you don't want to restart everything and if the changes are backward-compatible http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD